# Please Burninate [stackexchange]

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

### I hereby propose that *the tag* [stackexchange](/questions/tagged/stackexchange) be burninated.

The tag's wiki:

> [stackexchange](/questions/tagged/stackexchange) is for questions about the entire network of Q&A sites that make up the Stack Exchange network.

is circular to the *site* definition:

> Ask questions about issues that affect all Stack Exchange sites

<sup>[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour)</sup>

Theoretically speaking, ***all*** questions on the site should use this tag! However, only 1,281 questions do.

I think this tag is pointless and circular. Please burninate.

Comment: @nicael But this question is about an issue that was not -- nor was it asked to be -- answered by the "duplicate".

Comment: @Mooseman It really looks like a dupe: "Since all questions here should be about Stack Exchange, can we burninate this (...) tag?" Isn't that what you ask too?

Comment: @T.Verron That is answered with "yes" within the question. This is a request for burnination.

Comment: @Mooseman The dupe has the form of a question, but obviously implies a request, as confirmed by the tags.

Comment: @T.Verron But a different request.

Comment: Good dupe mark, Shadow Wizard.

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 actually other user found it first but didn't have enough rep to vote. So credit doesn't go to me this time. :-)

Comment: Oh I see. I'm one of the "other user" then XD

Comment: And me, but it doesn't count :D